# Inconsistency between date-time in terminal and clock

Tags: clock, date

I can't figure out why I have 5 hours difference between GUI clock and date command in terminal. My bios clock is set to GMT... Any ideas ?

```
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ date
mercredi 11 avril 2012, 02:48:47 (UTC-0500)
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Paris'
Local time is now:      Wed Apr 11 09:49:02 CEST 2012.
Universal Time is now:  Wed Apr 11 07:49:02 UTC 2012.

franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ tail /etc/timezone 
Europe/Paris
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ date
mercredi 11 avril 2012, 02:49:21 (UTC-0500)
franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Paris'
Local time is now:      Wed Apr 11 09:49:27 CEST 2012.
Universal Time is now:  Wed Apr 11 07:49:27 UTC 2012.

franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ date
mercredi 11 avril 2012, 02:49:30 (UTC-0500)

franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ sudo cat /etc/default/rcS
#
# /etc/default/rcS
#
# Default settings for the scripts in /etc/rcS.d/
#
# For information about these variables see the rcS(5) manual page.
#
# This file belongs to the "initscripts" package.

TMPTIME=0
SULOGIN=no
DELAYLOGIN=no
UTC=yes
VERBOSE=no
FSCKFIX=no

franck@franck-ThinkPad-T61:~$ sudo hwclock --show
mer. 11 avril 2012 07:49:48 CDT  -0.555705 secondes
```

Comment: is the `TZ` environment variable set to anything?

Comment: Thanks you're right. Didn't catch that TZ was also set as America/Chicago in my ~/.profile file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you're right. Didn't catch that TZ was also set as America/Chicago in my ~/.profile file...